# Gta 5 online account is not transferring

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So i just got an xbox one and I used to pay gta 5 on my xbox 360, but before I got the xbox one I had a ps4, and transfered my gta 5 online account from the 360, and it wont let me transfer the account because it keeps saying i have no data on my social club account even though i do.

So my main question is: Are you allowed to transfer from one console to 2 next gen consoles?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can transfer only once. But you'd better try opening a ticket on Rockstar Support website to clarify this and/or ask them if they can help you with your request.

Before opening that ticket, make sure:

1) your **xbox one** and **xbox 360 accounts** with which you are trying to make a transfer are the **same**.

2) make sure, that **xbox account id** is **linked with Rockstar Social Club account** on: https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/settings/linkedaccounts

for more info please see:
https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-Transfer-from-Xbox-360-or-PlayStation-3-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-and-PC